# Upgrading 5.6 to 5.7 without losing any data

Tags: mysql-5.6

I want to upgrade MySQL from 5.6 to 5.7 but I already have the existing databases and tables. How should I upgrade without losing any data?

Comment: First thing: take a mysqldump!!!

Answer (score 3):

The upgrade path is MySQL 5.6 -> MySQL 5.7

see [Upgrading MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html)